# What does Atletico Madrid do tactically different since Diego Simeone took over?

Tags: football, tactics

[Atletico Madrid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atl%C3%A9tico_Madrid) has beaten Barcelona 2-0 [recently in the Champions League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015%E2%80%9316_UEFA_Champions_League_knockout_phase#Quarter-finals) and they have always posed a serious threat. Other teams have floundered against Barcelona. Apart from utilising [Antoine Griezmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Griezmann)'s skills, what has [Simeone](https://g.co/kgs/viSWK) done tactically since his arrival?

Comment: As there were some close votes, I've edited the question so that is can attract factual, not opinionated, answers.

Answer (score 1):

Some of them are, all players are committed in defensive duties. Even players with offensive roles they try to recover balls. High pressure over the oponent. They practice a lot for corners and free shots and they have much better results on that now than before. They practice more and they are more prepared and are more effective at counterattacking

Comment: Could you provide some references for this answer?

Comment: you arent going to find much sources in english. Besides I am a native spanish speaking person. Here there is one in spanish http://tn.com.ar/deportes/esencial/antifutbol-no-es-pecado-jugar-con-el-estilo-del-cholo-simeone_671733 "I want an agressive, seasoned, strong, counterattacking team" one of his definitions

Comment: BTW; most of what I've written comes from spanish speaking ESPN commentators and people from other sport tv networks. I can't really give links for that :)

Comment: @Pablo you could still mention that in your answer, so people know where you got the info. :)

Answer (score -2):

More than committed in defensive duties I'd say that most of the players are committed to their manager because they trust Simeone and all of them have given 200% of their potential.

Players like Griezmann didn't want to quit because they have learned a lot and improved their skills with Simeone.

Apart from Wenger, Simeone is the European trainer with more seasons in the same club in a row.

Answer (score -6):

I don't know but I've heard someone say that there were 6 defenders in the match. SIX. And Barca's formation was 4-3-3 so 2 defenders can mark one attacker.

And since Griezmann is fast he can bypass the defense of Barca.

Oh, and It was the first match that messi haven't made a shot to the goal since 2011 : 0

Comment: I've searched for formations and lineups of the match from the internet and found out that the 6-3-1 was just fake-talk, nothing much. They were in 4-1-4-1 formation.

Comment: I would like to play against teams who put 6 defenders on three attackers. My midfielders and full backs could have the time of their live